# Why does my JS queue only return first word instead of whole string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, jestjs, queue

Why is it only dequeuing 'first' instead of 'first in line'?
As you can see in the following test result the expected value is "first in line", but the received value is only "first", what is going on?

**this is my queue class:**

```
function Queue() {}

Queue.prototype.arr = [];
Queue.prototype.sz = 0;

Queue.prototype.enqueue = function(n) {
  this.sz++;
  this.arr.push(n);
}

Queue.prototype.dequeue = function() {
  if(this.sz === 0) {
  return undefined;
  }
  else if(this.sz > 0){
  this.sz--;
  return this.arr.shift();
  }
}

Queue.prototype.size = function() {
  return this.sz;
}
```

**this is my test:**

```
it('returns queued string', function() {
    queue.enqueue('first in line');
    expect(queue.size()).toBe(1);
    expect(queue.dequeue()).toBe('first in line');
  });
```

**and this is the test result:**

```
● returns queued string

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "first in line"
    Received: "first"

      76 |     queue.enqueue('first in line');
      77 |     expect(queue.size()).toBe(1);
    > 78 |     expect(queue.dequeue()).toBe('first in line');
         |                             ^
```

Comment: `queue` should be an instance of `Queue`. Are you declariing `const queue = new Queue()`?

Comment: `sz` and `arr` should probably be own properties.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in this code that splits strings, so my glass ball is telling me the true culprit is not shown.

Comment: @ASDFGerte could you test it yourself? I swear this is everything. I had to cut some extra test code because it wouldn't let me post too much code, but it was just successful test results about queueing and dequeuing some ints.

Comment: Your test code looks fine. It should work as `.shift` removes the first element from an array and return that. Hence, it should be `first in line`. Can you please crosscheck the value in `this.arr` ? It should be `['first in line']` instead of `['first', 'in', 'line']`

Comment: Your code has some awkward behavior, most notably, it uses instances, but behaves like a singleton (in the case of `sz` even more weird, as you will get instance properties overlapping the prototype one). Also, "I swear this is everything" can't be true, as you at least need a `const queue = new Queue();`, as has been mentioned in other comments. From only the parts you show though there is no reason for your described behavior though, you must be omitting some crucial part (run on some website, code part missing, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's how I solved it, I rewrote it like this:

```
class Queue {
  constructor() {
  this.arr = [];
  this.sz = 0;
 }

enqueue(n) {
  this.sz++;
  this.arr.push(n);
}

dequeue() {
  if(this.sz === 0) {
  return undefined;
  }
  else if(this.sz > 0){
  this.sz--;
  return this.arr.shift();
  }
}

size() {
  return this.sz;
}
}
```